# Having trouble displaying code

Tags: javascript, html, string, loops, for-loop

How can i get this piece of code to display on screen? I'm making a program that notices when a letter is out of sequence i.e abce it will display d. I've got the core function working but I'm having trouble displaying it. Here is what I've got so far. Thanks.

HTML

```
<form id="Awesome">
  <label>Input Text Here: </label><input type="text" id="txtBox">
  <br><br>
  <label>Missing Letter: </label><input type="text" id="Results">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="Execute" onclick="displayMissingLetter()">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function displayMissingLetter(str) {
  var numbers = str.split('').map(function(letter) {
    return letter.charCodeAt(); 
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if (numbers[i+1] - numbers[i] > 1){
      return String.fromCharCode(numbers[i] + 1);
    }    
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: What should happen with the result of displayMissingLetter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function displayMissingLetter() {
  var str = document.getElementById('txtBox').value;
  var letters = []; 

  var numbers = str.split('').map(function(letter) {
     return letter.charCodeAt(); 
  });


  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if (numbers[i+1] - numbers[i] > 1){
        letters.push(String.fromCharCode(numbers[i] + 1));
        }    
    }
  document.getElementById('Results').value = letters.join('');
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! You just forgot to add code to actually manipulate the DOM to display the value :)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're not passing any parameters to the `displayMissingLetter` function (`onclick="displayMissingLetter()"`). It expects a string as the first parameter which means that you should call it using something like this `onclick="displayMissingLetter(txtBox.value)"`

The second problem is that you're not doing anything with the return value of this function, it seems that you want to set the resulting value as the value of the `Results` input. If that is the case, you can do something like this:  `onclick="Results.value = displayMissingLetter(txtBox.value)"`

Another approach will be using something like the example below.

```js
function getMissingLetter(str) {
  var numbers = str.split('').map(function(letter) {
     return letter.charCodeAt(); 
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  if (numbers[i+1] - numbers[i] > 1){
      return String.fromCharCode(numbers[i] + 1);
      }    
  }
  return undefined;
}

Execute.onclick = function(){
  var userInput = txtBox.value;
  var missingLetter = getMissingLetter(userInput);
  if(missingLetter){
     Results.value = missingLetter;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="Awesome">
  <label>Input Text Here: </label><input type="text" id="txtBox">
  <br><br>
  <label>Missing Letter: </label><input type="text" id="Results">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="Execute">
</form>
```